# JavaScript regular expression using character class with quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I have:

```
var regex = /[\d]*/;

var str = 'tom123is456';

var match = str.match( regex );

document.write(match);
```

I was expecting to get back 123456.

From my understanding the askterisk (*) tells the engine to match 0 or more occurences of something and the plus sign (+) tells the engine to match one or more occurences of something. Now the "\d" is short for 0-9.

In the above example I get back nothing. When I use the plus (+) sign I get back 123. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mix up global search and *no*/*one* and more matches consequently. If you need to match all digits in a string, use global `g` flag:

```
'tom123is456'.match(/\d/g);  // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

To get consequent token matches use `*` or `+`:

```
'tom123is456'.match(/\d+/g);  // ["123", "456"]
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags

Comment: Thanks. Why in using the + do I only get back 123?

Comment: @robertrocha Because regex matches the first sequence of more than one digits.

Comment: aND WHY DOES THE ASTERISK RETURN NOTHING?

Comment: @robertrocha It doesn't return nothing, it returns `""`, i.e. empty string. This is exactly the first match of *"zero or more digits"*, i.e. `t` as a zero-lengthed digit.